# @Valid bean validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Consider the two frameworks shown below. Here I need to validate the bean

**Controller**

In controller I m using @Valid and does the java validation. Works fine

```
@RequestMapping("")
void testIt(@Valid @RequestBody User user){

}
```

**Normal Spring application without controller**

Is there any way to do validation here. Its not a controller and @Valid doesn't work here.
Anyways to use @Valid or any similar type of validation for normal function?

```
void testIt(@Valid User user){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable method validation by declaring beans of type org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor and org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean and annotating the class containing testIt() with the @Validated annotation.

```
@Validated
@Component
public class TestIt {
  public void testIt(@Valid User user) {
  ...
  }
}
```

ConstraintViolationException will be thrown if validation errors occur when calling testIt(). Also, make sure you have Hibernate Validator in your classpath.